# Calculation of average session in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm calculating the average session for users, visiting a webapp.
Each visit of a page creates a visit record in my database.

Now there are ~40000 vistis with 10000 individual tokens, so my calcualtion takes very long.
Someone got an idea to increase the speed of calculating the average session?

Now I'm collecting uniqe tokens. Then I look up for each token the first and the last visit to calculate the difference.

```
diff = 0
token = self.visits.where(created_at: self.statistic_range).pluck(:token).uniq

token.each do |tok|
  visits = self.visits.where(created_at: self.statistic_range, token: tok).order('updated_at asc')
  diff += (visits.last.created_at - visits.first.created_at).round
end
return diff / token.size
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an n+1 query problem here. Your code is doing 10,000 + 1 individual SQL queries.

Why don't you try fetch all the visits once and store them in an array and then do the calculations in memory.

```
visits = self.visits.where(created_at: self.statistic_range).to_a
token = visits.pluck(:token).uniq
...
```

This will obviously eat a lot of RAM and CPU, but most likely it won't be as bad as running 10,001 SQL queries.